# How to display polygons from .json data in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to display a floorplan to my webapp using d3.js and vue js. The data comes from a .json file and is in a geojson format. I generated some test data from [this geojson website](https://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0). I was thinking I could use the d3.js path function to plot each different object to a svg element. Would this be the correct way to go about doing this? I have looked at [this](http://bl.ocks.org/michellechandra/0b2ce4923dc9b5809922) tutorial to make a united states map from geojson data. I was thinking this would be the right way to do it if you inputted different data. However my program spits out the proper lines [image: console] but does not display anything to the webapp. I included my code in below. Any help is greatly appreciated and im open to possibly using a different java script library but d3js is preferred.

```
  var promises = [
      d3.json("../static/data.json")
      //d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamjanes/udemy-d3/master/08/8.04/data/us-map.json")
    ]

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
        ready(data[0]);
    })

    function ready(us) {
      console.log(us)
        svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
              .data(us.features)
              //.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
                .attr("fill", "grey")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("stroke", "#fff")
                .attr("stroke-width", .2)
    }
    }
```

Comment: The example is from d3js version 3, but you used v5 in your code. They are not compatible

Comment: By default d3.geoPath does not project data, it will just take coordinates and treat them as pixel coordinates. But your coordinates are geographic coordinates, without the projection you draw them as pixel coordinates: eg 104W, 38N rendered at [-104,38]. You'll need to select a projection, for example d3.geoAlbersUsa and pass that to the path, for example, `d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoAlbersUsa());`

Comment: @AndrewReid thank you that seemed to work