# How to plot GeoJson data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to display a floorplan to my webapp using d3.js and vue js. The data comes from a .json file and is in a geojson format. I generated some test data from [this](https://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0) geojson website. I was thinking I could use the d3.js path function to plot each different object to a svg element. Would this be the correct way to go about doing this? I have looked at [this](http://bl.ocks.org/michellechandra/0b2ce4923dc9b5809922) tutorial to make a united states map from geojson data. I was thinking this would be the right way to do it if you inputted different data. However my program spits out random rectangles to the webapp. I think this may be becauseof the projection I am using but Im not sure. I havent used d3.js like this before so its all new to me. I included my code in below. Any help is greatly appreciated and im open to possibly using a different java script library but d3js is preferred.

```
createFloormap(){
      var svg = d3.select("svg")
      var width = +svg.attr("width")
      var height = +svg.attr("height")


      var path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoAlbersUsa().scale(500))
      //var path = d3.geoPath()
      //var path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoMercator().scale(100))



      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([1, 10])
          .rangeRound([600, 860]);

      var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
          .domain(d3.range(2, 10))
          .range(d3.schemeBlues[9]);

      



    var promises = [
      d3.json("../static/data.json")
      //d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adamjanes/udemy-d3/master/08/8.04/data/us-map.json")
    ]

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
        ready(data[0]);
    })

    function ready(us) {
      console.log(us)
        svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
              .data(us.features)
              //.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
                .attr("fill", "grey")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("stroke", "#fff")
                .attr("stroke-width", .2)
    }
    }
  },
```

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -144.140625,
              45.583289756006316
            ],
            [
              -65.390625,
              45.583289756006316
            ],
            [
              -65.390625,
              69.28725695167886
            ],
            [
              -144.140625,
              69.28725695167886
            ],
            [
              -144.140625,
              45.583289756006316
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              9.4921875,
              39.36827914916014
            ],
            [
              159.609375,
              39.36827914916014
            ],
            [
              159.609375,
              70.02058730174062
            ],
            [
              9.4921875,
              70.02058730174062
            ],
            [
              9.4921875,
              39.36827914916014
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: the web app]

Comment: Can you share the specific file that you are using? I'm not certain if it is the commented out file - would help in providing a definitive answer.

Comment: @AndrewReid yes I just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My apologies, I mislead you when [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63005654/how-to-display-polygons-from-json-data-in-d3-js?noredirect=1#comment111419296_63005654) on your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63005654/7106086). I read the code and saw an obvious issue - but missed the reference to a floor plan - which for the coordinates given was unlikely to be measured in latitude/longitude pairs. The answer below would be appropriate for a floor plan in lat/long pairs (as would be exported from geojson.io and because projection is less relevant at the building scale) or a geojson floor plan with coordinates in meters/feet.*

**Geojson in an arbitrary Cartesian coordinate system**

You don't have geographic coordinates consisting of latitude/longitude pairs measured in degrees (as I thought when commenting), you have coordinates consisting of x,y values measured in some unit like metres or feet.

To project these corodinates we do not want to use `d3.geoSomeProjection` because these project latitude/longitude pairs on a sphere to a 2d plane. Nor do we want to use a null projection (the default projection for d3.geoPath) because that treats geojson coordinates as pixel coordinates (we can use a null projection when the coordinates in the geojson have been already been converted to pixel values - we know we don't want a null projection here because we have negative values).

Instead we can use `d3.geoIdentity` (the `geo` prefix indicates it is just part of the `geo` module of D3 but it doesn't require geographic coordinates). This "projection" allows us to apply some projection methods to the data, namely `.center()` or `.scale()`. D3 also has two convenience methods that set both simultaneously: fitExtent and fitSize which stretch and translate specified geojson to given dimensions:

```
var projection = d3.geoIdentity().fitSize([width,height],geoJsonObject)

var projection = d3.geoIdentity().fitExtent([[left,top],[right,bottom]],geoJsonObject)
```

So, with your data we get:

```js
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -144.140625,
              45.583289756006316
            ],
            [
              -65.390625,
              45.583289756006316
            ],
            [
              -65.390625,
              69.28725695167886
            ],
            [
              -144.140625,
              69.28725695167886
            ],
            [
              -144.140625,
              45.583289756006316
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              9.4921875,
              39.36827914916014
            ],
            [
              159.609375,
              39.36827914916014
            ],
            [
              159.609375,
              70.02058730174062
            ],
            [
              9.4921875,
              70.02058730174062
            ],
            [
              9.4921875,
              39.36827914916014
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

var width = 500;
var height = 300;
var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);

var projection = d3.geoIdentity().fitSize([width,height],data)
var path = d3.geoPath(projection);

  
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data.features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d",path);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

One thing to note is that SVG coordinates space, to which d3.geoIdentity is treating coordinates as being in, has the opposite convention as might be expected: y=0 is at the top of the SVG with y values increasing as one moves down. If your coordinates appear to be upside down, then you can use `d3.geoIdenity().fitSize(...).reflectY(true)`